# How to optimize the page load using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created Snow Flakes When I reduce the value to generate snow flakes as something like

```
window.setTimeout(generateSnow, 1);
```

or If i increase the snow flakes appearance in loop as like

```
// generate snow using a for loop
        for(i=0; i<20; i++){

....
....
}
```

By using this it webpage get it slow sometimes it ask the popup to debug script or stop script.
I am not sure how to solve this inorder to work with any number of flakes.
Or Whether I did some mistakes ?
Here is the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vicky081/4cZdu/17/)

**EDITED:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){    

    // get the height and width of the browser window
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    // set the height and width of the #snowingScreen div equivalent to that of the window's
    $('#snowingScreen').css('height', windowHeight);
    $('#snowingScreen').css('width', windowWidth);  


    // this function is to generate snow randomly scattered around screen
    function generateSnow() {

        // generate snow using a for loop
        for(i=0; i<4; i++){

            // randomize the top position of the snow
            var snowTop = Math.floor(Math.random()* (windowHeight/2) );     

            // randomize the left position of the snow
            var snowLeft = Math.floor(Math.random()* (windowWidth - 10) );  

            // appending the snow to the #snowingScreen
            $('body').append(

                // generate the div representing the snow and setting properties using various jQuery methods               
                $('<div />')
                    .addClass('snow')
                    .css('top', snowTop)
                    .css('left', snowLeft)
                    .css('position','absolute')
                    .html('*')
                    .click(function() {
                        alert('You Clicked');
                    })
            );

        }

        // repeat the generateSnow() function
        window.setTimeout(generateSnow, 1);     

    }

    // this function is to alter the top of each snow, using the handy .each() jQuery method
    function snowFalling(){

        // move the snow
        $('.snow').each(function(key, value){

            // check if the snow has reached the bottom of the screen
            if( parseInt($(this).css('top')) > windowHeight - 80 ) {

                // remove the snow from the HTML DOM structure
                $(this).remove();
            }       

            // set up a random speed
            var fallingSpeed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);

            // set up a random direction for the snow to move
            var movingDirection = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);

            // get the snow's current top
            var currentTop = parseInt($(this).css('top'));      

            // get the snow's current top
            var currentLeft = parseInt($(this).css('left'));                

            // set the snow's new top
            $(this).css('top', currentTop + fallingSpeed ); 

            // check if the snow should move to left or move to right
            if( movingDirection === 0){

                // set the snow move to right
                $(this).css('left', currentLeft + fallingSpeed );   

            }else {

                // set the snow move to left
                $(this).css('left', currentLeft + -(fallingSpeed) );                

            }                   

        }); 


        // repeat the rollIt() function for each 200 microseconds
        window.setTimeout(snowFalling, 200);            

    }        

    // call the function when the document is loaded completely
    generateSnow();   
    snowFalling();

});
```

Any Suggestion would be great.

Comment: for animation loop is a bad option it just make script unresponsive

Comment: @ArunKillu Thanks for your Info Then What shall i do

Comment: Please post your code here. It's hard to read it in the fiddle, because the page is non-responsive!

Comment: Your loop will create infinite amount of Divs, this is probably too much to handle for a browser. Make some function that will delete the 'fallen' snow so you keep approximately the same amount of divs.

Comment: You might want to check this one...http://jsfiddle.net/4cZdu/18/

Comment: @nkmol I already did this to remove div   if (parseInt(jQuery(this).css('top')) > windowHeight + 400) {

                          jQuery(this).remove();
                    } In that what can i stabilize the div generate and fall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be better solution using css3 animation or jquery animation but following changes make your code responsive    [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4cZdu/26/)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){    

        // get the height and width of the browser window
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();

        // set the height and width of the #snowingScreen div equivalent to that of the window's
        $('#snowingScreen').css('height', windowHeight);
        $('#snowingScreen').css('width', windowWidth);  


        // this function is to generate snow randomly scattered around screen
        function generateSnow() {

            // generate snow using a for loop
            for(i=0; i<4; i++){

                // randomize the top position of the snow
                var snowTop = Math.floor(Math.random()* (windowHeight/2) );     

                // randomize the left position of the snow
                var snowLeft = Math.floor(Math.random()* (windowWidth - 10) );  

                // appending the snow to the #snowingScreen
                $('body').append(

                    // generate the div representing the snow and setting properties using various jQuery methods               
                    $('<div />')
                        .addClass('snow')
                        .css('top', snowTop)
                        .css('left', snowLeft)
                        .css('position','absolute')
                        .html('*')
                        .click(function() {
                            alert('You Clicked');
                        })
                );

            }

            // repeat the generateSnow() function

        }

        // this function is to alter the top of each snow, using the handy .each() jQuery method
        function snowFalling(){

            // move the snow
            $('.snow').each(function(key, value){

                // check if the snow has reached the bottom of the screen
                if( parseInt($(this).css('top')) > windowHeight - 80 ) {

                    // remove the snow from the HTML DOM structure
                    $(this).remove();
                }       

                // set up a random speed
                var fallingSpeed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);

                // set up a random direction for the snow to move
                var movingDirection = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);

                // get the snow's current top
                var currentTop = parseInt($(this).css('top'));      

                // get the snow's current top
                var currentLeft = parseInt($(this).css('left'));                

                // set the snow's new top
                $(this).css('top', currentTop + fallingSpeed ); 

                // check if the snow should move to left or move to right
                if( movingDirection === 0){

                    // set the snow move to right
                    $(this).css('left', currentLeft + fallingSpeed );   

                }else {

                    // set the snow move to left
                    $(this).css('left', currentLeft + -(fallingSpeed) );                

                }                   

            }); 


            // repeat the rollIt() function for each 200 microseconds



        }        

        // call the function when the document is loaded completely
        window.setInterval(snowFalling, 200); 
        window.setInterval(generateSnow, 200);
    });
```